# Highcharter - Deselect variables in the legend in the code On Rstudio

Tags: r, graphics, shiny, r-highcharter

I'm currently working on a database with lots of variables, the problem is that it's horrible in a graphic. But with highcharter, I founded that I can click in the legend to select/deselect a variable. The problem is that I don't found anything to do this directly with R code.

I don't want to hide it totally in the legend like it can be done with showInLegend or hideInLegend.

Picture that show before deselecting:

[image: Picture that show before deselecting]

Picture that show after deselecting:

[[image: Picture that show after deselecting][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHQSw.png)

Comment: Both images seem to be the same. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and create a reproducible example and/or show us a sample of what you want your output to look like

Comment: I made a mistake here, i edit that. And what i want to do is do the same that on the pictures but directly with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used the javascript code :

```
jsCode <- JS("function(event) {
if (!this.visible )
return true;

var seriesIndex = this.index;
var series = this.chart.series;

for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++)
{
if (series[i].index != seriesIndex)
{
series[i].visible ? series[i].hide() : series[i].show();
} 
}
return false;
}")
```

To use it on your highcharts graphics, add :

```
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(events = list(legendItemClick = jsCode)))
```